# Level of support in Monotouch for SQLite

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am wondering what level of support the latest MonoTouch has for using SQLite.  The closest information I can find is this article here which referes to limited support in v1.2 however it concedes that you may run into run time errors while using this.

This is what I found on the Xamarin website: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/System.Data

This really scares me.  Is there any documentation out there indicating what current level of support Xamarin has for SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak about the changes in System.Data support past that article, but I think it's quite common for folks to use [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/), or better yet [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) instead. Csharp-sqlite is an independent port of SQLite. And sqlite-net is "better yet" in the sense that its a minimal library where you can drop a single file in your project and use it to support sqlite on the various mono platforms. Yet it has nice features still such as "strongly typed queries" due to reflection-based ORM. So if you don't need a full Sqlite driver its a good option.

Greg Shackles did a nice seminar on x-platform dev with Monotouch/droid back in April where he covers these and other libraries: http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/04/25/cross-platform-mobile-development-seminar/

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/System.Data) is outdated, it's about MonoTouch 1.2 and the latest MonoTouch's version is [6.0](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_6/MonoTouch_6.0).

I'm using Sqlite with [Vici CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/Projects/CoolStorage/MonoTouch) in [two apps on App Store](http://skahal.com/category/apps/): easy and no problems at all. I've never see any runtime errors using Sqlite.